CPU thread count query with wmic for registry key
I'm trying to write a little cmd script to query the cpu with wmic to get the thread count applied to a registry key.
I have this code so far.
for /f "tokens=2 delims=^=" %%t in ('wmic cpu get NumberOfLogicalProcessors /value ^| find "="') do (
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Ndis\Parameters" /v "MaxNumRssThreads" /t REG_DWORD /d %%t /f  
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" /v "MaxNumRssThreads" /t REG_DWORD /d %%t /f
)

I get this error after running this little script in a batch file:
C:\Windows\System32>(
 /f add   KLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Ndis\Parameters" /v "MaxNumRssThreads" /t REG_DWORD /d 8
 /f  add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" /v "MaxNumRssThreads" /t REG_DWORD /d 8
)
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Specify valid numeric value for '/d'.
Type "REG ADD /?" for usage.
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Specify valid numeric value for '/d'.
Type "REG ADD /?" for usage.

It does print the 8, but says its not a numeric value for some reason. Anyone know whats causing it not to apply the key correctly?
I was expecting the registry key to be applied with the thread count query (8).

The first thing I'd ask is that you open a Command Prompt window and look at the output from typing set n, then pressing the [ENTER] key. I'd wager that there's a line beginning with NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS= which may be useful to you.

If you must still do it your way, then the following method is the standard way of overcoming to 'odd' output from WMIC, (and additionally perform it all in a single batch file command line): @For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe CPU Get NumberOfLogicalProcessors /Value 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "="') Do @For /F %%H In ("%%G") Do @For %%I In (Ndis Tcpip) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\%%I\Parameters" /V "MaxNumRssThreads" /T REG_DWORD /D %%H /F 1>NUL.

And just for completeness, using the already existing environment variable mentioned in the first comment, @For %%G In (Ndis Tcpip) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\%%G\Parameters" /V "MaxNumRssThreads" /T REG_DWORD /D %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% /F 1>NUL.
